# Bound $\sum_{k=1}^n P(B<k) P(B\ge k) $ where $B$ is Binomial $(n,p)$

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-distribution

Let $B$ be Binomial $(n,p)$. Is there a simple but tight bound on
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n P(B<k) P(B\ge k) 
\end{align}
as function of $n$?

Here is my attempt, which I think is suboptimal,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n P(B<k) P(B\ge k)  &\le  \sum_{k=1}^n  P(B\ge k) \text{           use $P(B<k) \le 1$ }\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n  e^{-2n(p-\frac{k}{n} )^2},
\end{align}
where in the last step we have use a tail bound for Binomial (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds)). There are some other better tail bounds that can improve this inequality.
However, I think we still lose a lot in step.

Is there a better way of approaching this? That would result in a tight bound for large $n$?

Answer (score 2):

We can approximate $B_{n}$ as a normal random variable:
$$\hat{B}_{n} = (B_{n}-np) /\sqrt{np(1-p)} \sim N(0,1)$$
Then,
$$P(B_{n} < k) = P\left(\hat{B}_{n} < (k-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}\right)$$
$$P(B_{n} \geq k) = P\left(\hat{B}_{n} \geq (k-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}\right)$$
Therefore,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\sum_{k=1}^n P(B<k) P(B\ge k) \rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x)) dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Is approximately the Riemann integral of $\Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x))$ from $-np/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ to $n(1-p)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ with step sizes of $1/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

In conclusion:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n P(B<k) P(B\ge k) \approx \sqrt{\frac{np(1-p)}{\pi}}$$
(Approximately as in their ratio goes to $1$.)